# cant sign in user, not getting the right response, trying to get user with token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox

Im having a lot of problems in my first django, rest-framework application.

1. Im not getting the token after Im signing up, instead of

```
 "user" : {
   "_id":"1",
   "username":"you", 
   "email":"a@a.com"
 }, 
 "token" : 'fjdjfkljgkghgjkl'
}
```

Im getting

```
{
 "_id":"1",
 "username":"you", 
 "email":"a@a.com"
}
```

what could be the problem here?

2. When Im trying to sign in, postman tells me:

```
{"username" :["user with this username already exist.]}
```

and Im trying to sign in not sign up.
why is this happening?

3. When Im trying to get all the todos that belongs to the user I get this error:

```
{"details":"Authentication credantials were not provided" }
```

, instead of an empty list, why is that?

4. how can I get the user if I have only the token?

serializer code:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('_id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwarg = { 'password' : {
            'write_only' : True
        }}


class SignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('_id', 'username', 'email', 'password')

        extra_kwarg = { 'password' : {
            'write_only' : True
        }}

    def create_user(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])

        return user

class SignInSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get("username", None)
        password = data.get("password", None)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is None:
           raise serializers.ValidationError('A user with this username and password is not found.')

        return user
```

viewset code:

```
class SignUpViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SignUpSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
        user = serializer.save()

        return Response({
            'user': SignUpSerializer(user, context = self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            'token': AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        })

class SignInViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SignInSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
        user = serializer.validated_data

        return Response({
            'user': UserSerializer(user, context = self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            'token': AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        })

class GetUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ] 
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: please add relevant code from your Serializer and views here. It will be hard and time consuming to navigate from code base.

Comment: just added the code from the serializer and viewset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues which you have listed are mainly cause of point `2`.

`{"username" :["user with this username already exist.]}`

If you read it more carefully, it says user already exist. So it must be trying to create a `user` instead of letting them login. And this behavior is excepted because the way you have used serializer in your `SignInViewSet`.

```
class SignInViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SignInSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = SignInSerializer()
        user = serializer.validate(attrs=request.data)

        return Response({
            'user': UserSerializer(user, context = self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            'token': AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        })
```

I have removed `get_serializer` because I am not fimilar with it, but it should work fine. Main take away is that use `serializer.is_valid()` only when you are `updating` or `creating` stuffs in database. As you can see right now it is trying to create a new user instance and that's why the error `user with this username already exists`. After this you should have your `token` and then set `Headers` in your `Postman`, if everything goes well you can access your user with `request.user` in your views.

**UPDATE:**

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializers import SignInSerializer, SignUpSerializer, UserSerializer
# Create your views here.

class SignUpView(APIView):
    serializer_class = SignUpSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = SignUpSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
            return Response({'user': serializer.data, 'token': token})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class SignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwarg = { 'password' : {'write_only' : True }}

    def create_user(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=validated_data['username'], email=validated_data['email'], password=validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Since you are not using `viewsets` I have shifted `SignUpView` to `views.py` and I have removed your extra validation from `serializers` as it won't work, instead if there is any error in your serializer it will be handled in your views, check `if serializer.is_valid()` and `else` statement. And your `urls.py` in `user` app will be something like this.

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import SignUpView
from django.urls import path

# user_router = routers.DefaultRouter()

# user_router.register(r'sign_up', SignUpViewSet, basename='sign_up')
# user_router.register(r'sign_in', SignInViewSet, basename='sign_in')
# user_router.register(r'user', GetUserViewSet, basename='user')

urlpatterns = [
    path('sign_up/', SignUpView.as_view()),
]
```

and `backend/urls.py` will be

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
from todo.urls import todo_router
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/todo/', include(todo_router.urls)),
    path('api/auth/', include('user.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'index.html'))
]
```

Check output: [image: here]

**NOTE:** `self.get_serializer(data = request.data)` is only available for `ViewSets`, that's why `views.py` has been edited. You can similarly update your other views too.

Comment: thank you for the replay! unfortunately the problem still happens, i think somehow the viewset is not updated, because when i sign up, i get {_"id":1, "username":"name"} instead of {"user":{_"id":1, "username":"name"}, "token":"some-token"}, I've tried to close the virtual environment and open again, still nothing. also, why when i sign up it returns my password? this line should have handle it -  extra_kwarg = { 'password' : {'write_only' : True}}

Comment: `AuthToken` takes `user` object not the serialized version. I would change my answer but I cloned your project and the way you are creating user is really messed up. Why are you creating a `User` model from `models.Model`? Have a look [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html). Second I haven't used `ViewSet` that's why I missed it `post`,'get` method are not supported, instead it supports actions such as `create` or `list`. In order to fix it start by having a proper model for `Users`.

Comment: Also `ViewSet` requires a `queryset`, that was the first thing I had to fix from repo. For simplicity use `APIView` for `SignUp` or `SignIn`

Comment: when i change to APIView - i get ```AttributeError: type object 'SignUpViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'```, I changes the user, and now Im using the user model from 'django.contrib.auth.models ', and changed the sign in to 'def list`. unfortunately nothing working ..

Comment: update your github, i will check and then update here as required.

Comment: thank you for all the help! I can see that the issue is with this line:  user = authenticate(username=username, password=password).. when i changed it to this -         user = User.objects.get(username=username, password=password), it signing up my user and return everything currently.. but if the user doesn’t exist it throw this error: django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist. how can I catch it and raise it myself? and using User.objects.get is bad authentication?

Comment: `try:` normal code `Except User.DoesNotExist:` raise here. Yes `authenticate` would be better.

Comment: I didnt knew that python have something like try {}catch{} , thank you so much for you help! I really appreciate it ! thank you!